# Are Zxing and Zbar the only scanners for android application development?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zxing, zbar

I'm about to start working on some android development and was wondering after a lot of internet research that are:

**Zbar and Zxing** the only scanning tools out there that can be implemented into android apps is there no other way or getting a code scanner or any other methods of getting a scanner in ?

Also how do people find it adding Zbar and Zxing into android based projects,does it always work according to plan ?

Please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native Android detection API:
https://developers.google.com/vision/?hl=en

https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes#1

Comment: Yes, I am using now in my project. It's great.

Comment: How long did it take to implement ?

Comment: fast, you can access the second link and try it.